# Highcharts format

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to work-out the format for Highcharts.

In one of the demos, there is the following call:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=range.json&callback=?', function(data) {code to build the chart
```

When the call is made, data similar to the following is returned:

```
callback([
```

/* 2009-01-01 */
[1230771600000, -5.8, 0.1],
[1230858000000, -4.1, 1.4],
[1230944400000, -0.5, 4.1],
[1231030800000, -8.9, -0.7],
[1231117200000, -9.7, -3.7],
[1231203600000, -3.4, 3.2],
[1231290000000, -3.9, -0.2],
[1231376400000, -2.4, 6.7],
[1231462800000, 3.8, 6.9],
[1231549200000, 3.1, 6.8]
]);

The problem I am having is that I want to deliver the data through my own AJAX call that will have a result that will contain the graph data as well as some other things. However, I cannot seem to get the format correct so HC can read it. I read their pages about the formats, but with no luck.

I think the problem is the 'callback([]);' container needs to be removed, but when I do that, the data is not displayed in the chart.

lee

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same problem once. your **json has to be parsed** before giving it into highcharts series
high charts series accepts an array in this format

```
[[float,float],[float,float]]
```

whereas your unparsed json would try to give

```
[[String,String],[String,String]]
```

after removing your 'callback([]);' container , you need to parse the individual '[x,y]' points before supplying it to the series object

one way of doing it(in js):

> 1. String[] jsonComponents= jsonWithoutContainer.split(",");
> 2. Iterate each of the jsonComponents array.
> 3. for each jsonComponent - String[] xyComps=jsonComponent.split(",");
> 4. x=parseFloat(xyComp[0]); y1=parseFloat(xyComp[1]); y2= parseFloat(xyXomp[2]);
> 5. put these in an array, using array1.push(x,y1) and the supply it to the chart.series(array1)

Comment: Thanks Austin. I can sorta see what you are saying. However, I'm not 100% convinced. In the call I put in my post, the results are being returned in JSON format. So, how is the way they are returned their different than delivering them as my part of my own JSON formatted data?

Answer (score 0):

This callback is used for JSONP. You can simply use standard JSON to achieve that:

```
[[1230771600000, -5.8, 0.1], [1230858000000, -4.1, 1.4], [1230944400000, -0.5, 4.1] ... ]
```

Without any comments, function etc. If data would look this way, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out.

When jQuery loads all the data, it converts it into a string. Before it can be used by Highcharts, it needs to be converted back to an object using `$.parseJSON(data)`.

Thanks Pawel and Austin for trying to help.